# Moved Xcode files to new computer and not working anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have recently moved my Xcode projects to a new folder and since then I have been getting this build error, where `{APP_NAME}` is then name of the app and `{USER_NAME}` is my user name. I'm not sure why it repeats four times or how to fix it.

> Showing Recent Issues
>   Module 'Firebase' in AST file '/Users/{USER_NAME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1JMTVUPAUMMZ2/Firebase-1BFOFO9DEO92S.pcm' (imported by AST file '/Users/{USER_NAME}/OneDrive/My Files/My Documents/Home/Programming/Projects/{APP_NAME}/App/{APP_NAME}/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/{APP_NAME}-Bridging-Header-swift_31A0BT03HVTKK-clang_1JMTVUPAUMMZ2.pch') is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load '/Users/{USER_NAME}/OneDrive/My Files/My Documents/Home/Programming/Projects/{APP_NAME}/App/{APP_NAME}/{APP_NAME}/module.modulemap'?
>
> Clang importer creation failed
>
> Module 'Firebase' in AST file '/Users/{USER_NAME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1JMTVUPAUMMZ2/Firebase-1BFOFO9DEO92S.pcm' (imported by AST file '/Users/{USER_NAME}/OneDrive/My Files/My Documents/Home/Programming/Projects/{APP_NAME}/App/{APP_NAME}/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/{APP_NAME}-Bridging-Header-swift_31A0BT03HVTKK-clang_1JMTVUPAUMMZ2.pch') is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load '/Users/{USER_NAME}/OneDrive/My Files/My Documents/Home/Programming/Projects/{APP_NAME}/App/{APP_NAME}/{APP_NAME}/module.modulemap'?
>
> Clang importer creation failed
>
> Module 'Firebase' in AST file '/Users/{USER_NAME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1JMTVUPAUMMZ2/Firebase-1BFOFO9DEO92S.pcm' (imported by AST file '/Users/{USER_NAME}/OneDrive/My Files/My Documents/Home/Programming/Projects/{APP_NAME}/App/{APP_NAME}/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/{APP_NAME}-Bridging-Header-swift_31A0BT03HVTKK-clang_1JMTVUPAUMMZ2.pch') is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load '/Users/{USER_NAME}/OneDrive/My Files/My Documents/Home/Programming/Projects/{APP_NAME}/App/{APP_NAME}/{APP_NAME}/module.modulemap'?
>
> Clang importer creation failed
>
> Module 'Firebase' in AST file '/Users/{USER_NAME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1JMTVUPAUMMZ2/Firebase-1BFOFO9DEO92S.pcm' (imported by AST file '/Users/{USER_NAME}/OneDrive/My Files/My Documents/Home/Programming/Projects/{APP_NAME}/App/{APP_NAME}/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/{APP_NAME}-Bridging-Header-swift_31A0BT03HVTKK-clang_1JMTVUPAUMMZ2.pch') is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load '/Users/{USER_NAME}/OneDrive/My Files/My Documents/Home/Programming/Projects/{APP_NAME}/App/{APP_NAME}/{APP_NAME}/module.modulemap'?
>
> Clang importer creation failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try deleting derived data (which holds the module cache), cleaning the project and rebuilding?

Does your project define a module map file in the build settings (under Packaging) - I don't know if it should or should not(!) but it's an avenue to explore.

Comment: @Ben could you let us know which part of the answer was helpful in solving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to make sure that in the build settings for your target the `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` in Build Settings is correctly referenced. It should be the folder containing the modulemap.

Answer (score 1):

Check search paths in the project's build settings.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well, since when I import a third party SDK header, which contains another SDK public header in it, I met this error. And my solution was to import the umbrella header which in your case is 'Firebase', above the third party SDK header, and problem was resolved.

Hopes this solution will help someone who has the same error with me.